# Replacing multiple SUMIF()'s for uniques

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet with multiple columns containing "Customers" and "Hours". I wish to find each unique customer, and then calculate the sum for each unique customer.

```
// Customer columns
{A3:A; D3:D; G3:G; J3:J; M3:M; P3:P; S3:S}

// Hours columns
{C3:C; F3:F; I3:I; L3:L; O3:O; R3:3; U3:U}
```

I find the unique Customers with this formula:

```
=sort(filter(unique({A3:A; D3:D; G3:G; J3:J; M3:M; P3:P; S3:S}),NOT(ISBLANK(unique({A3:A; D3:D; G3:G; J3:J; M3:M; P3:P; S3:S})))))
```

And I can calculate the sum of a unique customers' hours by using a helper column, `W`:

```
=sumif(A3:A,W14,C3:C)
+sumif(D3:D,W14,F3:F)
+sumif(G3:G,W14,I3:I)
+sumif(J3:J,W14,L3:L)
+sumif(M3:M,W14,O3:O)
+sumif(P3:P,W14,R3:R)
+sumif(S3:S,W14,U3:U)
```

This works. However, I need to insert the `SUMIF()` formula for each unique customer. I have to do this manually since Google Spreadsheet is not clever enough to replace only `W14` with `W15`, `W16` and so on.

How do I calculate the sum of hours for each unique customer without manually modifying my `SumIf`-formula?

A spreadsheet is here: [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T-y9fZLarBUqLOhhprSXcB4EvCxPr25zBhBde7G6cvo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have added a link to the google spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY({A3:C; D3:F; G3:I; J3:L; M3:O; P3:R; S3:U}, 
 "select Col1, sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  order by sum(Col3) desc
  label sum(Col3)''")
```

[image: 0]